# Any solution to convert .yuv file to h264 file on Mac?

Tags: macos, cocoa, yuv, x264

I want to develop an app for mac which can record the current screen.But now I have trouble on not knowing how to encode .yuv file I got from CGImage.Somebody told me to encode with x264 or ffmpeg,I am not sure if these are the right choice for OS X development.If anyone has any experience in doing this,I really appreciate that you could tell me.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x264 is a great library and I highly recommend it. On mac you also have the option to use the built in encoder. Part of AVFramwork I believe. It should uses less power and CPU then x264, but produce slightly larger files.

Answer (score 0):

x264 is probably one of the best encoders out there for your job. You can get it [here](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html).

For a more detail usage of all the commands, such as quality setting and fps, you can find it [here](http://mewiki.project357.com/wiki/X264_Settings).